# c# linq to xml: add child element to specific parent element based upon value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm making an XML configuration file editor in c# by means of LINQ to XML.  I have run into difficulty inserting child nodes where specific parent values are present.

My present code:

```
var xdoc = XElement.Load(config.ConfigPath);
....
xdoc.Descendants("grandparent")
.Where(a => a.Element("parent")
.Value == "targetvalue").FirstOrDefault()
.Add(new XElement("grandchild", grandchildvalue));
```

yields:

```
<grandparent>
     <parent>
     <grandchild>
```

rather than the intended:

```
<grandparent>
     <parent>
          <grandchild>
```

At this particular point in the code, only the grandparent and parent nodes have been created, and the grandchild element is being created along with its respective value.  How do I make the grandchild element subordinate to the parent element?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ should've returned the `<parent>` element instead :

```
xdoc.Descendants("grandparent")
    .Elements("parent")
    .FirstOrDefault(o => (string)o == "targetvalue")
    .Add(new XElement("grandchild", grandchildvalue));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Unfortunately, this method still yields an output like before with the parent and grandchild elements listed on the same line/level.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.  Your response does produce the correct result, when modified to:

```
 xdoc.Descendants("grandparent")
    .Descendants("parent")
    .Where(a => a.Attribute("name").Value == parentvalue).FirstOrDefault()                                                                            
    .Add(new XElement("grandchild", grandchildvalue));
```

As it turns out, my previous xml structure was wrong.  In giving the parent node a value rather than an attribute, I was getting output like:

```
<parent>parentvalue</parent><grandchild>grandchildvalue</grandchild>
```

where they were on the same level.  Setting the parent's value via an attribute allowed for the grandchild's value to be set as subordinate to the parent's.  Thank you for helping me to find this silly beginner's mistake!